# Segfault when launching pthreads for the second time

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I've got a program that does some calculations etc, and use pthreads for launching some threads. This works well.

However I need to launch the same set of threads several times over for a benchmark type of thing. When i launch them for the second time i get a segfault (core dumped).

Selected Code:

pastebin alternative (missing first mutex line)
Should inlude anything related to the problem:
http://pastebin.com/5iUsy8L2

```
function()
{
pthread_mutex_t pmutex;
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&pmutex);

    pthread_t pthreads[CPUTHRDS];
    launch_threads(pthreads);

    /* Unlock and start timer */
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&pmutex);
    tot_time = -msecond();

    /* Join taskthreads when they are done */
    join_threads(pthreads);
    tot_time += msecond();

    //<do something>
}
}

void launch_threads(pthread_t *pthreads)
{
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

printf("#HOST# Starting Task Threads\n");    

/* Launch the CPU threads */
for (int i = 0; i < CPUTHRDS; i++)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "launchthread %d\n", i);
    int rc = pthread_create(&pthreads[i], &attr, cpu_thread, NULL);
    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
printf("#HOST# CPU-Threads started: %d\n", CPUTHRDS);

pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
}

void join_threads(pthread_t *pthreads)
{
int rc = 0;
for(int i=0; i < CPUTHRDS; i++)
    {
        void *status;
        rc = pthread_join(pthreads[i], &status);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("#HOST# Thread %d joined\n", i);
    }
    printf("#HOST# All threads joined\n");
}

void *cpu_thread(void *arg)
{
unsigned long thid = pthread_self();
fprintf(stderr, "started %lu\n", thid);
}
```

Output

```
#HOST# Starting Task Threads
launchthread 0
launchthread 1
#HOST# CPU-Threads started: 2
started 46969086678784
started 46969084577536
#HOST# Thread 0 joined
#HOST# Thread 1 joined
#HOST# All threads joined
#HOST# Starting Task Threads
launchthread 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Been trying to remove any dependency on existing variables but it still fails on the second time over.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: I don't see how this can even compile. Where's the real program?

Comment: It's about 2k lines of code. I included the relevant parts as i mentioned

Comment: So, first thing that you do is cut down or rewrite your program to a very small example. Which will probably show you exactly where your bug is and you won't need us.

Comment: Yea, you're right, the stripped down version actually worked. Which makes it slightly more odd that it crashes where it does. I'll look into it further on my own. I was certain I had done something wrong with the whole creating pthreads after joining them. Thanks